# How to get a specific elements text with a generic tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using the following html

```
<div class="span4">
<h3>Someones Name</h3>
<p><a class=btn href="">Bio</a></p>
</div>
```

is it possible using Jquery/javascript , that when the user clicks button the text in  above the button can be returned. Is it possible to only return the h3 above the button if the page has many instances of this pattern of html? The only difference between each  block is that Somes Name changes.

for instance

```
<div class="span4">
<h3>Name1</h3>
<p><a class=btn href="">Bio</a></p>
</div>
<div class="span4">
<h3>Name2</h3>
<p><a class=btn href="">Bio</a></p>
</div>
```

It would be nice if each btn click/bound event would only return Name1 and Name2 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to get to the parent .span4 and then find the `h3`.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();// to prevent the default behavior of anchor a click from redirecting.
    alert($(this).closest('.span4').find('h3').text());
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4abDd/)**

Comment: Thanks this is both a viable option to the parents functions for to find the difference betweent the too. I found this page http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @AustinDavis Yup. In your case you just want to traverse till immediate parent. Closest will test itself and go only till it finds the parent that matches the selector. But parents() on that other hand will go till it reaches the top most level even if it finds a match and hence it is expensive and hard to maintain in your scenario if your html structure changes, you might end up with issues like this. http://jsfiddle.net/afR3v/

Comment: Wonderful argument and for stating that closest would be the most efficient, you sir have earned yourself the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this(jQuery version):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $h3 = $(this).parent().prev();
  alert($h3.text());
  return false;
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dm694/1/)

Comment: the alert statement didn't return anything :(

Comment: @AustinDavis: Just added a fiddle. Check my answer.

Comment: Works in your jsFiddle something, and yet on my page the alert still returns nothing. weird.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like:

```
$("a.btn").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var h3text = $(this).parents(".span4").find("h3").text();
   alert(h3text);
});
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DwEgK/)

Comment: Use closest instead of parents. parents is tricky and expensive than closest. See this example where it fails. http://jsfiddle.net/afR3v/